# How to disable HTTP chunking in WSO2 API Manager 3.2.0?

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2

I need to disable receiving http packets in chunked format in wso2 api manager 3.2.0 in order to protect against HTTP Request Smuggling , web cache poising and other server attacks .how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Disabling Message Chunking](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/3.2.0/learn/api-gateway/message-mediation/disabling-message-chunking/#disabling-message-chunking) from official API Manager documentation.

You can also try

```xml
<property name="DISABLE_CHUNKING" value="true" scope="axis2" />
```

Comment: tnx .in which file add this config ?

Comment: This property needs to be used in the `in-sequences` of the API that you have deployed in the API Manager. Once you specify the mentioned property in the `in-sequence` of an API, the chunking will get disabled for that specific API. If you want to disable the chunking for all the APIs that are deployed in your environment, then you can specify the above-mentioned property in a `global in mediation sequence`. Check the [doc](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/3.2.0/learn/api-gateway/message-mediation/changing-the-default-mediation-flow-of-api-requests/#creating-global-extensions) for more info.